# Less SourceMap file location relative to filesystem, not website

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, less, source-maps, grunt-contrib-less

I have a file structure that looks like this (simplified for brevity):

```
/less/
     /styles.less
/public/
       /css/
           /styles.css
           /styles.css.map
       /images/
       index.php
/gruntfile.js
```

Gruntfile.js:

```
less: {
    options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceMapFilename: 'public/css/styles.css.map',
        sourceMapURL: '/css/styles.css.map',
        sourceMapRootpath: '/'
    }
    files: {
        'public/css/styles.css': 'less/styles.less'
    }
}
```

In the index file: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">`

Now in dev tools, it's looking for `styles.less` in `http://localhost:3845/less/styles.less`, which doesn't exist, since only `/public/` is exposed to the website.

It used to map the files to my local machine correctly, without any additional steps, but doesn't anymore. I'm not sure what happened or how to set it up so it does.

I'm using the latest grunt-contrib-less (1.0.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser can not read the less folder, so remove your Less files to your public folder (or give the web server access to the `less` folder )

Alternatively set Less's `source-map-less-inline`  and `source-map-map-inline` options:

```
options: {
sourceMap: true,
sourceMapFileInline: true,
outputSourceFiles: true
}
```

The above puts the map, with the content of your Less files, into the CSS files.

Comment: Thank you. I used `outputSourceFiles: true` only and it seems to 'copy'(?) the less files into the public folder. Then the `sourceMappingUrl` references the less file. Seems to work well.